# EDSDK: can't set 'kEdsPropID_ImageQuality' property

Tags: c++, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm trying to set **kEdsPropID_ImageQuality** property in a small c++ application. I can set some other properties (kEdsPropID_ISOSpeed and kEdsPropID_SaveTo).

```
// set ISO 400
int intISO = 0x00000058;
EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_ISOSpeed, 0, sizeof(intISO), &intISO);
```

The code above works OK. But next code don't:

```
// change format from RAW to JPEG    
EdsUInt32 ImgQual = 0x0010ff0f;   // large jpeg or EdsImageQuality_LR;
EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(ImgQual), &ImgQual);
```

I need to switch from RAW to Jpeg and vice versa in my application. Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

At least, I found solution! It's very simple.

```
EdsUInt32 ImgQual = EdsImageQuality_LJF; // fine jpeg
```

or

```
EdsUInt32 ImgQual = EdsImageQuality_LR; // raw cr2
```

and then

```
EdsSetPropertyData (camera, kEdsPropID_ImageQuality, 0, sizeof(ImgQual), &ImgQual);
```